# Get decimal full value

Tags: vb.net, decimal

I have this number : `79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335`
If I convert it to decimal and output it, I will get this : `76.4200`

How can I get back the whole number from the decimal ?

Comment: save it in a temporary variable

Comment: @PedroEstrada How can I do this ?

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk: `79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335` is a decimal? How do you get `76.4200` from it?

Comment: I have a grid which have a `Decimal` column. I input this number(79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335) and then output it in a message box(76.4200).

Comment: -1 ? What is wrong with it ?

Comment: I think your culture setting may have comma as the decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you managed to output that number. Have you tried using a double? Can you show me the code in which you convert that to decimal?